# Download CSV file from Firebase Bucket Storage - Python

Tags: python, firebase

I have a CSV file staged daily in a Firebase storage bucket. I want to download this updated CSV file to my local machine on daily basis.

Using the following Python code, I am able to generate a link where I can click and the download the file. However, I am wondering if I can download it without any need of clicking the link generated.

```
import datetime
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage

### Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate("SDK_key.json")

### Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'XYZ.appspot.com',}, name='storage')

bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)

### Address of file to downloaded
blob = bucket.blob("test.csv")

### Generate a link and clicking on the link downloads the file
print(blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.timedelta(seconds=300), method='GET'))
```

Comment: I found solution to my problem through selenium automation to open the generated link dynamically and downloads the file on my local machine. I can read it in python from local machine and proceed

For .json or .text files, we can again use selenium in python along with BeautifulSoup to directly copy text/json data in a variable. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661808/how-to-grab-from-json-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase).

@James Daniels points out that `getSignedURL()` is the key component for retrieving your designated file, but you can do so by using the Firebase Admin SDK (acts as a wrapper for Google's Cloud Storage SDK).

Comment: Last command in above given python code is generating the download link for me. That's not a problem. I want to download the file from this link directly through python itself without any manual intervention. As of now, I have to open this URL manually and then file gets downloaded

Answer (score 0):

## Sample Code

- You don't need firebase-admin SDK to download a publically visible file
- Make sure you make the folder location visible, other wise you need to attach the access token, Which can only be fetched via client sdk.

#### Sample Firebase Security Rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
     // Explicitly define rules for the 'publicpath' pattern
    match /publicpath/{allPaths}{
      allow  write: if request.auth != null;    // Only auth users can write
      allow  read: if request.auth == null;   //Publically Readable
    }
    // This will be defined for everything else
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow  write: if request.auth != null;  // Only auth users can write
      allow  read: if request.auth != null;  // Only auth users can read
    }
  }
}
```

#### Python code to save file as CSV

Use pandas, If not installed use following code in `cmd` to install the package

```bash
pip install pandas
```

#### Sample python code

```py
import pandas as pd

def download_File(url):
    response = requests.get(url=url)
    path="downfile.csv"
    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("File Downloaded")

        df = pd.read_csv(url)   
        df.to_csv('outfile.csv')

        # with open('down.csv', 'w') as f:
        #     writer = csv.writer(f)
        #     for line in response.iter_lines():
        #         writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")

def main:
    storageBucket='XYZ.appspot.com'
    # publicpath/test.csv should be changed to 
    # publicpath%2Ftest.csv

    bucket_path="publicpath%2Ftest.csv"
    firebase_storageURL = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{}/o/{}?alt=media'.format(storageBucket, bucket_path)

    download_File(firebase_storageURL)


#Main program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

##### Remember to update the firebase storage rules